# Angular using $sce to allow some html, without allowing all of it(allow just my html)

Tags: angularjs

I have a filter that adds some html (parses users to href). I run it on user inputed text (a 'post' by user). and then displaying with `ng-html-bind={{post.text | parseUsers}}<P></p>`

this is the filter code

```
.filter('parseUsers', function($sce){
        return function(input, scope){
            if (input !== null && input !== undefined){
                var result, personPattern, personLinkTpl, userLink,personName, personLink;
                result = input;
                personPattern = /@[a-zA-Z\allowd_]+/gi;
                personLinkTpl = '<a href=\'#/users/%USER_ID%/\'>%USER%</a>';

                personMentions = input.match(personPattern);
                if (personMentions != null && personMentions.length > 0) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < personMentions.length; j++) {
                        personName = personMentions[j];

                        personLink = personName.replace('@', '').toLowerCase();
                        userLink = personLinkTpl.replace(/%USER_ID%/, personLink).replace(/%USER%/, personName);
                        result = result.replace(personName, userLink);
                    }
                }
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(result);
            }
        };
    })
```

Everything works correctly but the implication is that I shut down the ng-sanitize service on this html. and so I can post `<script>alert('hey')</script>` and it would work.

how can I assign trust **only** to my added html or to a specific regex and not everything? or maybe I should sanitize the input before starting to parse it? how is that done with $sce?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution by now? If yes, please post it